# Passing a variable or QString to function in SLOT(function()) C++

Tags: c++, qt

Quick question on using Qt with C++.

This is what I have right now, but I needed to create four functions, and I feel like that is very messy and I would rather have one function of which I can pass a variable or text to and clean it up.

MainMenu.cpp:

```
#include "mainmenu.h"
#include "ui_mainmenu.h"

MainMenu::MainMenu(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainMenu)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    connect(ui->nesButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(nesButtonPressed()));
    connect(ui->snesButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(snesButtonPressed()));
    connect(ui->genesisButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(genesisButtonPressed()));
    connect(ui->ps2Button, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(ps2ButtonPressed()));
}

MainMenu::~MainMenu()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainMenu::nesButtonPressed()
{
    ui->gameLabel->setText("NES");
}

void MainMenu::snesButtonPressed()
{
    ui->gameLabel->setText("SNES");
}

void MainMenu::genesisButtonPressed()
{
    ui->gameLabel->setText("Genesis");
}

void MainMenu::ps2ButtonPressed()
{
    ui->gameLabel->setText("PS2");
}
```

MainMenu.h:

```
private slots:
    void nesButtonPressed();
    void snesButtonPressed();
    void genesisButtonPressed();
    void ps2ButtonPressed();
```

But that has four functions. What I would like to do is the following, however I can't seem to get it to work.

MainMenu.cpp

```
connect(ui->nesButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(onButtonPressed("NES")));
connect(ui->snesButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(onButtonPressed("SNES")));
connect(ui->genesisButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(onButtonPressed("Genesis")));
connect(ui->ps2Button, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(onButtonPressed("PS2")));
```

And simply have one function:

```
void MainMenu::onButtonPressed(QString game)
{
    ui->gameLabel->setText(game);
}
```

Which would set the text of the label depending on what button is pushed. It just doesn't seem to work. I have set the function correctly in the header file, but I keep getting the error `QObject::connect: No such slot MainMenu::nesButtonPressed("NES")`

I've tried setting variable names, and defining them in the header file, but nothing seems to work. Hopefully someone can help.

Thank you in advance!

Edit, working code below:

MainMenu.cpp:

```
#include "mainmenu.h"
#include "ui_mainmenu.h"

MainMenu::MainMenu(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainMenu)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    signalMapper = new QSignalMapper(this);
    signalMapper->setMapping(ui->nesButton, QString("NES"));
    signalMapper->setMapping(ui->snesButton, QString("SNES"));
    signalMapper->setMapping(ui->ps2Button, QString("PS2"));
    signalMapper->setMapping(ui->genesisButton, QString("Genesis"));

    connect(signalMapper, SIGNAL(mapped(QString)), this, SLOT(onButtonPressed(QString)));
    connect(ui->nesButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), signalMapper, SLOT(map()));
    connect(ui->snesButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), signalMapper, SLOT(map()));
    connect(ui->ps2Button, SIGNAL(clicked()), signalMapper, SLOT(map()));
    connect(ui->genesisButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), signalMapper, SLOT(map()));

}

MainMenu::~MainMenu()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainMenu::onButtonPressed(QString game)
{
    ui->gameLabel->setText(game);
}
```

MainMenu.h:

```
signals:
    void clicked(const QString &text);

private:
    Ui::MainMenu *ui;
    QSignalMapper *signalMapper;

private slots:
    void onButtonPressed(QString game);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try using QSignalMapper, seems like an option for your particular problem
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsignalmapper.html

From docs:

> This class collects a set of parameterless signals, and re-emits them with integer, string or widget parameters corresponding to the object that sent the signal.

Comment: I read up on QSignalMapper, and I was able to get it to work! I'll update my OP with my new working code incase anyone wants to see.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the `QObject::sender()` method to find out which button the click came from

Dummy dialog class with 4 pushbuttons and a text label:

**dialog.h**

```
#ifndef MYDIALOG_H
#define MYDIALOG_H

#include <QDialog>
#include "ui_dialog.h"

class MyDialog : public QDialog, public Ui::Dialog
{
  Q_OBJECT
  public:
  MyDialog(QWidget *parent = 0) : QDialog() {
    setupUi(this);
    connect( pushButton_1, SIGNAL( clicked() ) , this, SLOT( buttonPressed() ) );
    connect( pushButton_2, SIGNAL( clicked() ) , this, SLOT( buttonPressed() ) );
    connect( pushButton_3, SIGNAL( clicked() ) , this, SLOT( buttonPressed() ) );
    connect( pushButton_4, SIGNAL( clicked() ) , this, SLOT( buttonPressed() ) );
  }

  public slots:
  void buttonPressed();

};

#endif
```

then for the `buttonPressed()` method

**dialog.cpp**

```
#include "dialog.h"


void MyDialog::buttonPressed()
{
  QPushButton *button = static_cast<QPushButton*>( sender() );
  if( button == pushButton_1 ) {
    label->setText("1");
  } else if( button == pushButton_2 ) {
    label->setText("2");
  } else if( button == pushButton_3 ) {
    label->setText("3");
  } else if( button == pushButton_4 ) {
    label->setText("4");
  }

}
```

and the main for completeness

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QApplication>

#include "dialog.h"

int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
  QApplication app(argc,argv);
  MyDialog dialog;

  dialog.show();

  return app.exec();

}
```

Comment: This breaks encapsulation by requiring the slot to know about every object that can call it. That's poor design.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Qt 5 with C++11 or above, you can use lambdas:

```
connect(ui->nesButton, &QPushButton::clicked,
        this, [this](){onButtonPressed("NES");});

connect(ui->snesButton, &QPushButton::clicked,
        this, [this](){onButtonPressed("SNES");});

connect(ui->genesisButton, &QPushButton::clicked,
        this, [this](){onButtonPressed("NES");});

connect(ui->ps2Button, &QPushButton::clicked,
        this, [this](){onButtonPressed("PS2");});
```

Comment: I liked the simplicity of that, however it didn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Error: Expected expression, `this, [this](){onButtonPressed("NES");});` with an arrow pointing to `[this]`.

Comment: @ConnorQuick it looks like you haven't enabled C++11 support in your .pro file.

Comment: Ahh, yes! Adding `CONFIG += c++11` to my .pro file fixed that problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could make it even simplier:

```
void MainMenu::buttonPlatformSelectorPressed()
{
    // This assumes the button text can be used for the label as well.
    QPushButton *button = static_cast<QPushButton*>( sender() );
    label->setText(button.Text());
}
```

and then connect all the four buttons to the same slot.